# Pyphon Tweepy api.get_user doesn't work

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

could anyone tell me what is wrong with my Pyphon code here? I am trying to use the get_user api by tweepy cursor, but it keeps telling me "this method does not perform pagination" But if I use user_timeline, it works perfectly fine.

Here is my code

```
for twitter in tweepy.Cursor(api.get_user, user_id="xxx", screen_name="xxx").items():
      print(twitter.text)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, I've never used tweepy but it seems that there is 2 way to iterate on a cursor with `items` and `pages`. Have you try with `pages` ? Otherwise,  "this method does not perform pagination" if you point one user are you sure you need to use a cursor ?

Comment: I think the get_user method just returns a single user object, so there's no need for pagination. There's no cursor parameter supported on the method. http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/api.html#user-methods

Comment: Thanks guys, I just solved the problem !

Answer (score 1):

The `get_user` API is for a single person, rather than a timeline. You can use it like this:

```
tweet = api.get_user(screen_name="JoeMayo")
print("Most recent tweet: " + tweet.status.text)
```

You don't need all 3 parameters, either an `user_id` or `screen_name`. Also, and you would have probably seen this, the most recent tweet is `tweet.status.text`, rather than `tweet.text`.

Comment: Thank you so much !